# initialFirstResponder not getting the focus ring on start

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, nsresponder

I set the `initialFirstResponder` of `window` in my AppDelegate on launch (to a custom NSTextField). I expected that this would cause the `NSTextField` derivative to launch with the blue focus ring around it - it does NOT. Only on a single TAB from the keyboard does this become the case...

I have worked around this by doing the following:

```
    window.initialFirstResponder = customTextField
    window.makeFirstResponder(window.initialFirstResponder)
```

but the above just seems wrong - like I'm doing the same thing twice.